# Implementing hyper::client::Connect for testing

Tags: rust

I'm trying to test some code that uses a `hyper::Client` by implementing my own `hyper::client::Connect` using a static response. I've got the types figured out, but can't figure out a runtime issue where `tokio-proto` complains saying `request / response mismatch`. Here's a simplified version of my code that demonstrates the failure:

```
extern crate futures;
extern crate hyper;
extern crate tokio_core;
extern crate tokio_io;

use futures::{future, Future, Stream};
use std::str::from_utf8;
use std::io::Cursor;

struct Client<'a, C: 'a> {
    client: &'a hyper::Client<C>,
    url: &'a str,
}

impl<'a, C: hyper::client::Connect> Client<'a, C> {
    fn get(&self) -> Box<Future<Item = String, Error = hyper::Error>> {
        Box::new(self.client.get(self.url.parse().unwrap()).and_then(|res| {
            let body = Vec::new();
            res.body()
                .fold(body, |mut acc, chunk| {
                    acc.extend_from_slice(chunk.as_ref());
                    Ok::<_, hyper::Error>(acc)
                })
                .and_then(move |value| Ok(String::from(from_utf8(&value).unwrap())))
        }))
    }
}

struct StaticConnector<'a> {
    body: &'a [u8],
}

impl<'a> StaticConnector<'a> {
    fn new(body: &'a [u8]) -> StaticConnector {
        StaticConnector { body: body }
    }
}

impl<'a> hyper::server::Service for StaticConnector<'a> {
    type Request = hyper::Uri;
    type Response = Cursor<Vec<u8>>;
    type Error = std::io::Error;
    type Future = Box<Future<Item = Self::Response, Error = Self::Error>>;

    fn call(&self, _: Self::Request) -> Self::Future {
        Box::new(future::ok(Cursor::new(self.body.to_vec())))
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut core = tokio_core::reactor::Core::new().unwrap();
    let handle = core.handle();

    // My StaticConnector for testing
    let hyper_client = hyper::Client::configure()
        .connector(StaticConnector::new(
            b"\
                 HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\
                 Content-Length: 8\r\n\
                 \r\n\
                 Maldives\
                 ",
        ))
        .build(&handle);

    // Real Connector
    /*
    let hyper_client = hyper::Client::configure().build(&handle);
    */

    let client = Client {
        client: &hyper_client,
        url: "http://ifconfig.co/country",
    };
    let result = core.run(client.get()).unwrap();
    println!("{}", result);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=4603feb41a59a69ea478f7d62af85c44&version=stable)

I'm guessing it's my use of the `Cursor` for `Io` that is incomplete in some way, but I'm failing to debug and make progress. One thought is that the writes to this `Cursor` the `hyper::Client` presumably makes are not working as expected. Maybe I need a combination of a `sink` for the writes and the static content for the reads? All ideas I've failed to make progress using!

Answer (score 2):

The reason the original code didn't work was because the reader side provided the response before the client sent the request, so `tokio-proto` errored out with `request / response mismatch`. The fix turns out to be non trivial in that first we need to arrange for the reader to block, or more specifically error out with `std::io::ErrorKind::WouldBlock` to indicate to the event loop that there isn't anything yet, but don't consider it an `EOF`. Additionally once we get the write which indicates the request has been sent and the tokio-proto machinery is waiting for a response, we use `futures::task::current.notify` to unblock the read. Here's an updated implementation that works as expected:

```
extern crate futures;
extern crate hyper;
extern crate tokio_core;
extern crate tokio_io;

use futures::{future, Future, Stream, task, Poll};
use std::str::from_utf8;
use std::io::{self, Cursor, Read, Write};
use tokio_io::{AsyncRead, AsyncWrite};

struct Client<'a, C: 'a> {
    client: &'a hyper::Client<C>,
    url: &'a str,
}

impl<'a, C: hyper::client::Connect> Client<'a, C> {
    fn get(&self) -> Box<Future<Item = String, Error = hyper::Error>> {
        Box::new(self.client.get(self.url.parse().unwrap()).and_then(|res| {
            let body = Vec::new();
            res.body()
                .fold(body, |mut acc, chunk| {
                    acc.extend_from_slice(chunk.as_ref());
                    Ok::<_, hyper::Error>(acc)
                })
                .and_then(move |value| Ok(String::from(from_utf8(&value).unwrap())))
        }))
    }
}

struct StaticStream {
    wrote: bool,
    body: Cursor<Vec<u8>>,
}

impl Read for StaticStream {
    fn read(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> io::Result<usize> {
        if self.wrote {
            self.body.read(buf)
        } else {
            Err(io::ErrorKind::WouldBlock.into())
        }
    }
}

impl Write for StaticStream {
    fn write<'a>(&mut self, buf: &'a [u8]) -> io::Result<usize> {
        self.wrote = true;
        task::current().notify();
        Ok(buf.len())
    }

    fn flush(&mut self) -> io::Result<()> {
        Ok(())
    }
}

impl AsyncRead for StaticStream {}

impl AsyncWrite for StaticStream {
    fn shutdown(&mut self) -> Poll<(), io::Error> {
        Ok(().into())
    }
}

struct StaticConnector<'a> {
    body: &'a [u8],
}

impl<'a> StaticConnector<'a> {
    fn new(body: &'a [u8]) -> StaticConnector {
        StaticConnector { body: body }
    }
}

impl<'a> hyper::server::Service for StaticConnector<'a> {
    type Request = hyper::Uri;
    type Response = StaticStream;
    type Error = std::io::Error;
    type Future = Box<Future<Item = Self::Response, Error = Self::Error>>;

    fn call(&self, _: Self::Request) -> Self::Future {
        Box::new(future::ok(StaticStream {
            wrote: false,
            body: Cursor::new(self.body.to_vec()),
        }))
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut core = tokio_core::reactor::Core::new().unwrap();
    let handle = core.handle();

    // My StaticConnector for testing
    let hyper_client = hyper::Client::configure()
        .connector(StaticConnector::new(
            b"\
                 HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\
                 Content-Length: 8\r\n\
                 \r\n\
                 Maldives\
                 ",
        ))
        .build(&handle);

    // Real Connector
    /*
    let hyper_client = hyper::Client::configure().build(&handle);
    */

    let client = Client {
        client: &hyper_client,
        url: "http://ifconfig.co/country",
    };
    let result = core.run(client.get()).unwrap();
    println!("{}", result);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=c0f434d3260f1cd5cf9f048ca96eabde&version=stable)

Note: This implementation works for simple cases, but I haven't tested more complex scenarios. For example one thing I'm unsure of is how large request/responses behave as they may involve more than 1 read/write call.

Comment: Many thanks for posting your solution, helped me a lot.